# Oracle 11 Merge statement not updating rows

Tags: oracle, merge

Debugging a Merge statement, syntax is:

```
    Merge into dest d
    Using (src) s
    On (d.id = s.id)
    When matched then
    Update set d.col = s.col
    Where d.col <> s.col;
```

Let’s say that column col is not null in both tables.
Also, src is a local collection, not a physical table.
I am seeing rows in dest not updated when they should be.

Has anybody seen this behavior?

If src has 10 rows matching dest, and 5 have d.col = s.col, and 5 have d.col <> s.col, does the Where clause evaluate to false and thus none of the 10 rows are updated?

Many thanks for those of you out there with experience with the Merge statement.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the data. Can you provide a sample?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] including DDL statements for the collection data type(s) and for the `dest` table and DML statements for some sample data in the `dest` table that you want updating and an example query that we can run that demonstrates the issue.